# Netbeans: Class file keeps getting deleted when main method is run

Tags: java, netbeans, server, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to build a TCP server using Netbeans. The problem is that when I run the main Server class I keep getting a NoClassDefFoundError for my class: Core/Store. The class file is there in the file directory after I clean and build but it disappears when I run the main Server class.

[image: Project Structure]

[image: Exception]

The store class doesn't rely on any external libraries and contains methods that add elements to lists and call methods from the dao classes.

Comment: There might be something with classpath for more info on your error look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java. If you still need help than you need to show code of Core.Store.